# Is it possible to attach to an already running gdb process?

Tags: linux, gdb, centos

Good morning, I started a gdb debug session several hours ago. Is possible to use gdb to attach to a process already being debugged by gdb?

I tried to attach as root but I get the following error message:

```
[root@localhost lirh5g_deb]# gdb ./MatchUpAccurate.exe  12327
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
/home/frank/DQT/MatchUpTest/lirh5g_deb/12327: No such file or directory.
```

We are using `Centos Linux Version 5.5`. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "already running gdb process"? You want to attach GDB to started GDB, that debugs some other process?

Comment: I think he means he wants to attach gdb to an already running application(one that he wants to debug).

Comment: @Kiril Korov , I started a gdb session several hours with the command: gdb ./MatchUpAccurate.exe. I would to attach to this gdb session so I can examine the current state of MatchUpAccurate.exe. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, not directly. Your only option, if you didn't use screen/tmux, is to search for a tty hijacker (it's possible to "steal" tty's - this is an ugly solution though) and grab the tty which has your existing gdb session

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just accepted your answer. Could you me where I could I find a Linux tty hijacker. My Google search for tty hijacker finds one article written in 1997 which discusses Solaris tty hijackers. However, it says in 1997 there were no Linux tty hijackers. Thank you

Comment: @Frank: As a tty hijacker wouldn't be a typical tool your best chance of finding one would be a security-related site, e.g. http://packetstormsecurity.org - You're looking for "file descriptor hijacking" or "tty hijacking".

Comment: Thank you for the link. I just downloaded fdjack.gz.